# Put ID before return function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In following code I have upgraded function from MYSQL into MYSQLI, I got some help in my previous posts and they said what should be done.. but now comes the question how to do it..

The thing is to set `id` before `return`, otherwise I still will be receiving user `ID = 1` no matter on which account I login.

```
function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    global $db_connect;

    $result = $db_connect->query("SELECT(id) FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");
    if (false === $result) {
        return false;
    }
    return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? id : false;
```

I tried to do as in my old `MYSQL` code, but then it gives error.
My old code:

```
    function user_id_from_username($username){
    $username = sanitize ($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT(id) FROM members WHERE username = '$username'"), 0, 'id');
}
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: What is `id` is here: `return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? id : false;`

Comment: it should be $id... am i wrong?

Comment: Not really he didnt even define $id but he should give $id the value of the id with fetch_assoc and return $id indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try it out but this should work right?
I also put $db_connect as parameter because its safer but it's up to you.

```
function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    global $db_connect;
    $result = $db_connect->query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '".$db_connect->real_escape_string($username)."'");
    if (!$result) {
        return false;
    }
    if($result->num_rows == 1){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $output = $row['id'];
    }
    else{
        $output = "Username does not exist in table or is a duplicate.";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Not really.. 

`Warning: Missing argument 2 for user_id_from_username(), called in C:\WebServer\htdocs\PicSide\includes\functions.php on line 147 and defined in C:\WebServer\htdocs\BETA\includes\functions.php on line 122`


`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\WebServer\htdocs\BETA\includes\functions.php on line 123`

Comment: You need to put the first parameter in the function which would be the mysqli connect variable, in your case $db_connect

Comment: I added `global $db_connect;` to the fucntion, but now it doens't login

Comment: Try to echo the function and see what it returns. It should return the id, if it does do this there is something wrong somewhere else in your code

Comment: I try to `echo` it but with no luck, I don't even know if I did it right, but according to replies from my previous post it is this function that makes everything wrong

Comment: Hmm well the function I made should return the id number from the username you put in the function. The problem might be somewhere else in your code but then again I didnt test it I might have an error. You could try and put the query in the return so you can see what it returns and if everything is alright.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23858/discussion-between-drikane-and-sinan-samet)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `fetch_array` or `mysqli_fetch_array`?

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// or
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// and returning
return $row['id'] ? $row['id'] : false;
```

Comment: Nearly, but that check on `$row['id']` seems rather pointless. OP was right to check `num_rows` first.

Answer (score -2):

```
return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? id : false;
```

should be

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) ===1 ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return intval($row['id']);
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I got error saying `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\WebServer\htdocs\BETA\includes\functions.php on line 127`

Comment: -1: You've just replaced OO notation for _a completely different paradigm_ and set of functions. You're right that the value of `id` must be retrieved, though.

Comment: ah, my bad, can u try it with mysqli_num_rows($result) same for mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: @Bodybag It works but still I get redirected to user where `ID = 1`

Comment: typo, not used to working with mysqli, but i still feel the answer isnt wrong. btw, OO programming would imply using PDO instead of mysqli? as i thought mysqli allows to use object notations, but thats about the same as using an std object..and that's only what i thought it was..

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php for the first line i read, this is making newer php programmers to think they are using OO-programming, but it only allows for the same syntax right? and since it allows both interfaces, my answer is not incorrect because of my preferred way of writing it. If you -1 me because you want the user to use OO programming, then perhaps you should enlighten the OP with the use of PDO objects which IS OO-programming and not simply a OO-syntax interface?

Comment: @Bodybag I think it is correct, everything leads to this function

Comment: @SztupY ah, yet again, can you ellaborate on how this is not an answer to the question?

Comment: @Drikane are you sure your sanitisze function returns the value u want to? and perhaps you have multiple rows using the same username? therefore it would only return the first row in the resultset as results would be ordered by the index from your table

Comment: @Bodybag sanitize doesn't make anything wrong here, it just protects data, it works on other functions

Comment: hmm i'm aware of what the function was supposed to do, and since you're doing a check for num_rows === 1 the other option of multiple users having the same name wouldn't be possible either. i'm expecting something else is wrong, but can't be found from this snippet alone, since you stated you are redirecting, are you sure that is using the correct value? perhaps u are using session variable to redirect, but forgot to change the value there?